# Face detection using hog features

Tags: classification, svm, face-detection

Currently for face detection I am using svm classifier over HOG feature set.But I need to implement other classifiers over those HOG feature set and compare the results between them .What other classifiers can I use other than svm?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of other classification algorithms, a simple logistic regression could be a starting point. You could use [logistic regression](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0030402614008511); implement [gaussian process based classifier](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW3.pdf/) or [random forrests/decision trees](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=4428937) and many others with respective pro's and cons.

See e.g. [this link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/classification/plot_classifier_comparison.html) for an overview